# Error 404 when clicking a link on a jsp page

Tags: spring

I have those 2 beans declared in the servlet.xml of my spring-app:

```
<bean name="/apple.htm" class="controller.AppleController"/>

<bean name="/secure/banana.htm" class="controller.BananaController"/>
```

Here is the banana controller:

```
public class BananaController implements Controller {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("returning contact view");
        return new ModelAndView("/banana");
    }

}
```

Here is the AppleController

```
public class AppleController implements Controller {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("returning contact view");
        return new ModelAndView("/apple");
    }

}
```

Here is the Apple.jsp (Banana.jsp is similar):

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/pages/include.jsp" %>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/pages/menu.jsp" %>
    <h2>Apple</h2>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac mauris ante. 
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the menu.jsp:

```
<a href="<c:url value="apple.htm" />" > Apple</a>
<a href="<c:url value="secure/banana.htm" />" > Banana</a>
<a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />" > Logout</a>
```

The problem is that once I logged-in, I can access the banana.htm, but then, if I go back on the "apple" page, it's gonna try to access the secure/apple.htm page, since I am already located in the /secure folder.

I know ../apple.htm would redirect properly, but nothing is telling me that the link is only gonna be clicked from banana.htm. I am sure I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<a href="<c:url value="/apple.htm" />" > Apple</a>
```